# need a book with a lot of java programming exercises and solutions

Tags: java

I am a CS student looking to increase my programming skills by practicing , I am looking for a book or website that has java programming questions and solutions. I am looking for intermediate/advanced exercises.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your question is important, but unfortunately it is not appropriate for this site. Please read the [site's FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see why this is so.

Comment: Try this website, it seems that list-questions are the whole point over there: http://www.slant.co/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try reading and re-writing key classes in the JDK.  There are thousands of them so I would start with the most common ones.  This will help you into the realm of advanced programming.  For expert programming, you really need 5 - 10 years experience as well.